# How to get rid of logs along with output on terminal when using vscode extention c/c++ with gdb

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

When I complete debugging my code on vscode using c/c++ extension with gdb, I get this logs on the terminal with my result, I have tried to read documentation on both vscode and gdb but I still get stuck. Do you guys know how to get rid of them. Thanks a lot!

[image: image link]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to get rid of the output, if I understand you correctly?

Click on the trashcan icon ️ on the top right corner of the terminal panel. This will kill the console.

When you start a new debugging session, a new console will spawn.️

Comment: @nhkduy811 Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: It's not, as the image I attached, I just want the output, not anything else. But I found the way. Thanks for your answer.